# Where should more complex methods go when using the repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, repository, repository-pattern

I have a project using the .NET MVC 5 framework where I am consuming the Poke API. The project is using a basic repository which is injected directly into the controller. In the repository, I have some basic methods like 'GetPokemonById', 'GetAllPokemon', etc.

In the controller, I have a private method which recursively finds the evolution chain for a pokemon, pseudo code below:

```
// Get the evolution chain from an initial Chain class
    private List<Pokemon> GetEvolutionChain(List<Chain> evolChain)
    {
        // List to contain the objects
        var PokemonList = new List<Pokemon>();
        // For each object in evolution chain, get the object from the API and add it to the list
        foreach (var pokemon in evolChain)
        {
            var PokemonFromApi = _Repo.GetPokemonByName(pokemon.name);
            PokemonList.Add(PokemonFromApi);
        }
        // Reloop through chain after all pokemon have been found above
        foreach (var pokemon in evolChain)
        {
            // If the current pokemon has an evolution, recursively run this function again to get the 
            // pokemon in the next chain
            if (pokemon.evolves_to != null)
            {
                // Add the returned pokemon to the list
                PokemonList.AddRange(GetEvolutionChain(PokeEvolution.evolves_to));
            }
        }
        // return the list of pokemon in the evolution chain
        return PokemonList;

    }
```

This works fine, however in its current state, I can not re-use it in other controllers so would like to move it somewhere else. The possible solutions I have considered are:

1. Move the method into the repository.

From my understanding, a repository is a presistence layer, so all of the data access should be in here to separate it from the controller and make it more testable. Since, the method is simply getting data, would it be appropriate to move it into the repository?

2. Move the method into a helper class

I have considered moving the method into a 'helper' class. If I then required the evolution chain, I could inject or create an EvolutionHelper object which could contain any helper methods relating to pokemon evolutions. However, since the method above relies on the repository, I would have to inject the repository from the controller as a parameter.

3. Adding a service layer

I could add a service layer between the repository and controller. The service layer could then have the method above and call the repo which is injected to get the data. However, adding another layer increases complexity. Also, Business logic would usually go in a service layer so I am not sure the method above would fit.

I am probably overthinking things but I am still getting my head around the repository pattern and most people seem to include only simple CRUD methods in a repository which led to my uncertainty. Any tips or links to a solution would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would go #2, or #1 if you have Stored Procedure or [recursive CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/) in the data base.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you categorize your logic. Basically, Repository should use for loading data with some simple logic (load by id, by type, by something). Service is to perform some business logic.

If you think your evolution chain gonna changed, more and more features will be added. Crazy logic will be added. I suggest to put it in service.

About the helper, to me, it is same as service. You just call it with different name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So would you suggest putting it into a service if I want to be able to re-use it across controllers? I suppose it is business logic in a way (because the user may want to see the evolution chain)

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents

- if you use an ORM like entity framework then there is not really needed for a *pure*, *generic* CRUD repository and you can put this code into the repository. I know lot of people would disagree with this but I think ORM already abstractifies CRUD operations so no need one more abstraction layer.

*But of course if want to do basic CRUD operations initiated from your controller then implement those too in your repository with calling the ORM's appropriate methods like context.Pokemons.Add(...); context.SaveChanges(); etc. And in your repository you can call for example in the GetEvolutionChain() method the GetAllPokemons() and other basic CRUD methods too.*

- if you don't use ORM then do CRUD repository and put this code into a service

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using EF so will consider the top solution.